# Google Calendar API Service Account Error 401 Invalid credential

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a Google Calendar Service Account.

Here are my credentials:

[image]

Here's my service account definition (Site Wide delegation for service account is enabled):

[image]

Here's my "Manage API client access" page:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
        string userName = "xxx@yyy.it";
        string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents };
        string ApplicationName = "Client per quickstart";
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"path\credentialjson.json").CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser(userName).UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName
        });
        // THIS REQUEST FAILS!!  
        var y = service.CalendarList.List().Execute();
```

The service is created correctly but all requests fail with this error:

> Code: 401, Message: "Invalid Credentials", Location: "Authorization", >LocationType: "header", Reason: "authError", Domain: "global"

I don't understand what I'm missing in the authorization header.

What should I set before the request that was not done when creating the service? Thanks!

Comment: To understand better. Do you want to use Domain-wide delegation? Also, keep in mind when setting the scopes in the  "Manage API client access" can take up to 24 hours and make sure your code is getting the service account file with its credentials

Comment: Yes I do. I set scopes in the "Manage API client access" one week ago...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to the Scopes you are using at the same time, because you are setting ***CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents***, this one will be the priority over ***CalendarService.Scope.Calendar***, because the Google APIs always take as priority the most restricted Scope (in this case ***CalendarEvents***).

And as you can see in the [CalendarList: list endpoint scopes](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#auth), the ***CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents*** is not a Scope you could use to  hit the endpoint you wanted to hit.

So, in your code you can delete the extra Scope and leave it like this:

```
string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the text over the top of your credentials

> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

Go to google developer console click `+ create credentials` pick service account from the drop down.  You need to ensure that you have downloaded the key fine for the Service account and not for the Oauth2 client.   The message you are seeing states that you have the wrong client type.  Try and download the service account key file again.

## example of service account credentials

[image]

You have created oauth2 credentials not service account creditnals.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                             .CreateScoped(scopes);
                    }

                    // Create the  Analytics service.
                    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Calendar Service account Authentication Sample",
                    });
```

Comment: I show all my credentials page. I use the service account credential: in my code the json is referred to quickstart-...@appspot.gserviceaccount.com client ID.

Comment: according to the error message your code is using the wrong file.

Comment: I've created a new service account credential, enable domain wide delegation, download the json created and set in admin console google my scopes. I obtain the same error again.